# C# Replace variable (direction) to single word ( mapping )

Tags: c#, .net, string, variables, replace

I have a problem with replacing text. I need to replace "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/"  to "OUT:/eee.txt". But the "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/" is already in variable. I can not just add @"C:/aaa/bbb/ccc". It is in a variable because I need use it to different paths e.g "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/" like "C:/aaa/ggg/fff/" etc. So this - > "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/" is a variable string a. It's kind of complicated I know, but I can't solve this problem..

Example:

```
string a (already has "C:/aaa/bbb/" INSIDE) ; 
string b; b=b.replace(a,"OUT:/");
```

Comment: The sample code you've posted appears to do what you're asking, but your question is very difficult to understand. Please add information showing exactly what goes wrong when you use the code you've posted.

Comment: I think you need a bit of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Management_of_dyslexia#Writing_systems_and_orthography) before we can help you with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something *like* this:

```
string a = "C:/aaa/bbb/eee.txt"" ;
string b = a.Replace("C:/aaa/bbb/", "OUT:/");
```

Answer (score 1):

Well no @ required for starters that's for backslash.

```
string target = "C:/aaa/bbb/ccc/"
string replaceWith = "OUT:/eee.txt"

string newText = oldText.Replace(target,replaceWith);
```